# Does ${f(x)=\ln(e^{x^2})}$ reduce to ${x^2\ln(e)}$ or ${2x\ln(e)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm confused with the expression  ${f(x) = \ln(e^{x^2})}$.I know the rule  ${\log_a(x^p) = p\log_a(x)}$. So does the given expression reduce to ${x^2\ln(e)}$ or ${2x\ln(e)}$?

Comment: Just editted the question slightly, please confirm it's still as you intend

Comment: The first, and since $\ln{e}=1$, the expression simplifies to $x^2$

Comment: Thanks for editing my question

Comment: @EVO no problem

Comment: Keep in mind: in the expression $e^{x^2}$ there is an implicit association, namely $e^{x^2}=e^{(x^2)}$. Of course without knowing this, one might assume the other association: $e^{x^2}=(e^x)^2$, in which case your alternate answer is correct; however, for towers of exponentials, also known as [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), that's not the conventional assumption.

Comment: Exactly as @LeeMosher said - this is a question of convention of notation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends whether by ${e^{x^2}}$ you mean

$${e^{(x^2)}}$$

or

$${(e^{x})^2}$$

If you intend to say the first, then the answer reduces to ${x^2\ln(e)=x^2}$
, and by convention by ${e^{x^2}}$ we usually are referring to ${e^{(x^2)}}$.

If you are referring to the second, the answer indeed reduces to ${2x\ln(e)=2x}$.

In any case - if you want to clear any ambiguity in expressions - always put brackets. But like I said, convention would dictate that ${e^{x^2}=e^{(x^2)}}$

Comment: @EVO Let me confirm that by convention $a^{b^c}$ always stands for $a^{(b^c)}$. If brackets lack then you can take it for sure that the author is aware of that convention.

Comment: @drhab editted my answer to get rid of the "I think"''s :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what you said, you know that:

$$\log_{a}(u^p) = p \cdot \log_{a}(u)$$

whenever $a,u,p$ take on values that make sense. In this instance, let $u = e$ and $p = x^2$. Then, we have:

$$\log_{a}(e^{x^2}) = x^2 \cdot \log_{a}(e)$$

Does that make sense? Since $a = e$ in this particular instance, it follows that the above can just be simplified to $x^2$.

**Edit:**

Okay, so I wasn't entirely sure what you were talking about initially because $e^{x^2}$, by itself, looks very different from $(e^x)^2$. If $u = e^x$ and $p = 2$, then we would have:

$$\log_{e}((e^x)^2) = 2\log_{e}(e^x) = 2x \log_{e}(e) = 2x$$

That's different from what what we got above yea?

Comment: Then I would say that you'd have to use the rule the change of base rule for logarithms. So, $$\log_{b}(a) = \frac{\log_{c}(a)}{\log_c(b)}$$. Then, if we would have $\log_{e^x}(e^{x^2}) = \frac{\ln(e^{x^2})}{\ln(e^x)} = \frac{x^2}{x} = x$, which only makes sense when $x \neq 0$, yea?

Comment: Sorrry @abhijeet I wasn't clear woth what i said. I was referring to (e^x) ^2

Comment: Yeap, I just addressed that in the edit. My bad haha. When you said base, I immediately just thought of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have $\ln(e^p)$ with $p = x^2$, so the correct reduction is $(x^2)\ln(e) = x^2$.